# how to display the largest number in stack on java

Tags: java, stack

I have that following code with class called stack, and a push method
can you help me please how to make a method that show the maximum ( the largest number ) number in stack? please help me with a very simple code I'm beginner I don't know in java just 5%

```
class stack1 {
    int maxsize,top;
    String arr[];
    int maxsize1;
    stack1 (int maxsize){
       this.maxsize=maxsize;
       arr=new String[maxsize];
       top=0;
    }
    void push (String data) {
       if (top<maxsize) {
          arr[top]=data;
          top++;
       } else {
          System.out.print("stack is overflow");
       }
    }
    public static void main(String arg[]) {
       stack1 s=new stack1(4);
       s.push("1");
       s.push("2");
       s.push("3");
       s.push("4");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using all the numbers in a String array as you're doing right now, you should use an integer array (`int[]`), a floating-point number array (`float[]`) or a different kind of numeric primitive data type (You can read more about them on the [Oracle Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)).

Assuming you name your `int[]` array `arr`, you can create a method which loops through all the numbers and will store the highest value which will be returned at the end of the function:

```
int maximumValue() {
  int maximum = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

  for (int value : arr) {
    if (value > maximum) {
      maximum = value;
    }
  }

  return maximum;
}
```

Comment: I wrote this , and it worked! thank you very much, but can you tell me what is mean " int maximum = Integer.MIN_VALUE;" ?

Comment: Java has constants for the minimum possible values that can fit inside of an integer, double, float, short, etc. As we want the maximum value and we are going to compare it with the previous values, we can set the starting value to the minimum value Java can store so the returned value is always guaranteed to be the largest.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the most efficient way but sorting does the trick:

```
    Arrays.sort(stack);
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(stack));
    System.out.println(stack[stack.length - 1]); //stack[stack.length - 1] is the max
```

The ordering you get will be lexographic because you are using strings.  To use numbers, you can change the stack to integers:

```
    String arr[]; becomes int arr[];
    void push (String data) becomes void push (int data)
    s.push("4") becomes s.push(4)
```

To get the max, you can add this method to your class:

```
int getMax() {
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    return arr[arr.length - 1];
}
```

Then you call it like:

```
int max = s.getMax();
```

Comment: but what do you mean by `     Arrays.sort(stack) ; ` what to put inside the brackets? should I put the object name " s " or " arr " ?

Comment: Arrays.sort will take the array, which in your case is the variable "arr", so Arrays.sort (arr).  You could add a new method: int getMax() { Arrays.sort(arr); return arr[arr.length - 1]; }

Comment: an erro occur it's "java - Non-static variable arr cannot be referenced from a static..."

Comment: correct, the method cannot be a static method.  You probably added the "static" keyword.  I have added this method to the answer.

Comment: I used the first answer code, for the maximum number  `int largest() {
       int max=0;
       for ( int value : arr){
           if (value > max)
               max=value;}
   
   return max;
   }`                                                                                                            but I want to use the same code with the smallest value on the stack, can you make a changes to that method? so it can work on smallest value, I tried to change  the greater then to smaller than, but it display "zero value " ...

Comment: by the way I tired to remove the static word, but I will not be able to run the program it say " NewEmpty does not have main class.... "